# where is cache_tag table used in magento2?

Tags: magento2, database

where is cache_tag table used in Magento2.

IS it save CACHE_TAG constant value in magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is constant and an table cache_tag maintaining it. We already have multiple cache tag and we can add more cache type. For example:

```
class %Namespace%\%Module%\Model\Cache\Type extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope{
  const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = '%cache_type_id%';
  const CACHE_TAG = '%CACHE_TYPE_TAG%';  
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool) {
    parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
  }
}
```